# Saving a generated image on Matlab Gui

Tags: matlab-figure, matlab-guide, save-image

I am trying to save an image that I generated on a Matlab Gui. I tried following code with a push button:

```
[Save,savename] = uiputfile('*.bmp','Save Figure As...')
fname=fullfile(savename,Save);
imwrite(handles.axes2, 'fname', 'bmp');
```

It doesn't work. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please tell us the result rather than simply saying it doesn't work. What result did you expect, and what happened instead?

Answer (score 0):

`imwrite` is for saving image data (as a matrix) to an image file. If you want to save the figure, you will want to use [`saveas`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html).

If you need to save an image of a specific axes, you can use `getframe` to save a screenshot of the specified axes, then convert this to an image using `frame2im` and *then* use `imwrite` to save this image data to a file.

```
frame = getframe(handles.axes2);
im = frame2im(frame);
imwrite(im, fname)
```